# Триггер из внешних источников для запуска сниппетов MODX

Tags: python, php, modx

Сделал я решение (на pyton), которое грузить по ftp файлы с локального пк на виртуальный хостинг.
Подскажите, как мне начать выполнение сниппета по окончанию загрузки файлов?

UPD: По итогу для автономного, удаленного запуска сниппета я использовал php файл который написал по рекомендации Anton Tarasov и python с библиотекой paramiko для работы с ssh на шаред хостинге

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключитесь к MODX API, выполните сниппет (опционально можно передать массив параметров, получить результат):

```
define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
require dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/index.php';
$modx->getService('error','error.modError');
$modx->setLogLevel(modX::LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
$modx->setLogTarget(XPDO_CLI_MODE ? 'ECHO' : 'HTML');

$output = $modx->runSnippet('yourSnippetName',array(
'someParam' => 'someValue'
));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, а чем можно запустить такой файл (соответственно не руками, а кодом)?

Comment: Возможно я нашел решение (а может и нет), через какую-нибудь библиотеку pyton для ssh попробую сделать это

Comment: я исходил из того, что у вас есть под руками PHP, может через bash?

Comment: Запуск файла должен осуществляться автономно по триггеру, поэтому я и хотел использовать библиотеку какого-либо языка.

Еще кое-что уточню, сам modx находится на шаред хостинге